# How to pass multiple values from a select2 as part of serialized form data to the controller in asp.net core 5 mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, jquery-select2, ajaxform

I have a form from which the user can submit serialized values to a Controller. There is a select2 from which the user can select one or more employee codes. How can I pass these multiple codes to the controller along with the other form values?

The posted data looks like this:

```
"appointmentCode=80814&employees%5B%5D=0387&employees%5B%5D=1055"
```

View:

```js
<form id="appointmentForm">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md small">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="appointmentCode">Appointment Code</label>
                            <input name="appointmentCode" type="text" class="form-control" id="appointmentCode" placeholder="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="employeeCode">Scheduled Employees</label>
                            <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="employees[]" id="selectedEmployeeCodes" multiple="multiple" style="width: 250px">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button id="buttonSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save Appointment</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();

    $('#buttonSubmit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var appointmentData = $('#appointmentForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Schedule/SetAppointment',
            data: appointmentData,
            cache: false,
            'themeSystem': 'bootstrap',
            success: function (results) {
                if (results === 'Ok') {                         
                } else {
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult SetAppointment(appointments_ALL_v appointments_ALL)
    {
        // submit data to database
    }
```

Model

```
public class appointments_ALL_v
    {
        public string appointmentCode { get; set; }
         
        public string[] employees { get; set; }
}
```

Is what I am attempting to achieve possible with this approach? I am hoping to be able to use the serialize function as it makes parsing this form (which actually contains over 50 input fields) so much easier.

Comment: While using the above approach what exact issue you are facing while you pass multiple values for Select2? Are you getting any errors or warnings?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT so when I make the employees property a string only the first employees value is set. I changed it to a string array as shown above, but that does not work, either. As is, it just becomes an empty array with no values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but what I ended up doing was placing a hidden element in the form which, upon submission of the form, would take all of the selected options values as a comma-delimited string. The Controller could then obtain that value from the serialized form data and split to get each employee.

```
$.each($('#selectedEmployeeCodes').find(':selected'), function (index, value) {
        eCodes = value.value + ',' + eCodes;
    });

$("#employeeCode").val(eCodes.replace(/,*$/, ""));


var appointmentData = $('#appointmentForm').serialize();
```

If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it!